# What are some better graphical designing software for drawing a product?

Tags: software-recommendation, designers, product-design

I am developing a product that have social relevance. I made a working model by using wood and implementing the parts inside the box body that I made. I also got funding from government for the project to develop it into a product.

My question is how can I design the product in plastic body by giving some aesthetics to my product? Is there some software that can solve my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your description references a box, which is a three dimensional object, it is practical to consider to use software which assists/implements three dimensional object design.

Depending on your willingness to devote hours to learning a software package, you can use a beginner level program that will take little time to learn and may provide your requirements, or you can use many hours to use a high end engineering package.

It's also practical to use a lower grade program to create prototype models and move on to more advanced programs as your requirements increase.

To that end, consider to examine a program known as [Tinkercad](https://www.tinkercad.com). It allows the user to drag and drop primitives to a workspace, editing and resizing and placing to generate three dimensional models.

I use Tinkercad to "build" models to better visualize the placement of components which will later to transcribed into a more technical parametric program. It reduces my error factor substantially and reduces workload as well.

You could "graduate" to Onshape for more advanced model creation, including automatically created drawings based on your models. Both of these programs are web based and no cost.

Another step up in the learning curve, accompanied by additional features and capability is Fusion 360. This program is free for hobbyists and small businesses and is partially web based, but uses a client package installed on your computer.

All of the above programs have tutorial videos available on the YouTube, allowing you to observe others work and progress and better decide which is best for you.

Comment: I do not recommend the avenue of simple first. Reality is that 3D is hard no matter what and something like fusion 360 and solidworks can be learned fast enough. However what i do suggest is that you get a tutor for 3D as that is saves you easily months if not years of time.

Comment: Oh and fusion is nolonger entirely free.

Comment: https://www.autodesk.com/campaigns/fusion-360-for-hobbyists ... This link states: 
Step 1: Check if you qualify

Fusion 360 is free for startups generating less than $100K per year in total revenue or wholly non-commercial hobbyist users. Review our legal terms of service page to make sure you qualify for free use.
  I was unable to find an indication that they've changed policy. Please post a link for clarification?

Comment: Its only free for 1 year. Previously it was renewable.